# Can I study complex analysis after measure theory and topology?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, measure-theory, soft-question

At my university one must usually study complex analysis and then measure theory & integration, probability & statistics, topology, algebra ii and numerical analysis ii afterwards. However, this semester I need to leave out some courses due to time constraint. Will there be a problem for learning these subjects if I take complex analysis in a later semester?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Ask your department.  Or the instructor of the course you want to take.  Probably in most cases, complex analysis is not used in measure theory and topology, so you will be OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a philosophical question with good arguments for both yes and no. There are alot of thing in complex analysis which can be developed without this machinery. I would say a doing a good calculus course like Baby Rudin is certainly sufficent to get alot out of a good book in complex analysis.

You will go back and realize new things after you taken measure theory etc and learn things you did not see the first time anyway.

One thing is for sure, you will never "learn" any subject in math. You only get used to it to a certain extent :).

Just do what feels right, you will make the mistake beliving this was best until you see that there would be alot of good coming doing the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

No problem . Rudin has a book ,Real and Complex analysis , he does measure theory first ,then complex analysis .